# ¿Cómo desinstalar composer de Mac?

Tags: php, laravel, macos, composer

He tratado de desintalar composer porque cambiaré de computador, corrí el siguiente comando `composer global remove laravel/installer` en Terminal, pero con eso es suficiente? o algún comando para desintalar completamente composer para Mac OS High Sierra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes abrir una terminal y buscar el path de composer de la siguiente forma:

```
which composer
```

Te debe retornar algo similar (en caso que no retorne nada es que no lo encuentra por lo que no lo tienes instalado o al menos no lo encuentra en el $PATH de las variables de entorno del sistema).

```
/usr/local/bin/composer
```

Luego lo que debes hacer el borrarlo con el siguiente comando

```
sudo rm -r /usr/local/bin/composer
```

Comment: me lanza este resultado: `rm: /usr/local/bin/composer: Permission denied`

Comment: usa sudo antes del comando para otorgarle privilegios